# ros2 run python executable not found

Tags: python, ros2, colcon, build, ardent

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am working with ROS2 ardent, using `Colcon` to build.

The build is suceessful and I can also see my executable in `<ws/build/package-name/build/lib/>` but still when I run the package using `ros2 run`, no executables are found.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299269/ros2-run-python-executable-not-found/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Marc Testier](https://answers.ros.org/users/36681/marc-testier/) on 2018-08-01**:
Did you source the setup.bash file in the install folder ??
`source <ros2_ws>/install/setup.bash`
You can add the command to ~/.bashrc so that you don't have to source every time you open a terminal.

**Comment by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on 2018-08-01**:
Yes, I have sourced the `setup.bash` file, still `no executable found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the problem.

In the `setup.py` file, I had a missing `,` for the last node in the `entry points`i.e.

> ```
> entry_points={
>     'console_scripts': [
>         'listener = demo_nodes_py.topics.listener:main',
>         'talker = demo_nodes_py.topics.talker:main'
>         'listener_qos = demo_nodes_py.topics.listener_qos:main'
>        
>     ],
> },
> ```

```
NOTE :  The missing `,` before the `listener_qos` node.
```

The strange thing here is, compiler compiles all the 3 nodes and I can see in the `<ws/build/package-name/build/lib/>` folder. Shouldnt the compiler just ignore the 3rd node `listener_qos` in this case ?

---

Originally posted by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) with karma: 667 on 2018-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a mixed C++/Python package. To install a Python executable in this package, I've found it sufficient to do this:

- Add the Python source file to `my_package/scripts`
- Add this line at the top of ^that file:  `#!/usr/bin/env python3`
- Make it executable with `chmod +x`
- Add an empty `__init__.py` file in `my_package/scripts`
- Add this to CMakeLists:

> ```
> install(PROGRAMS  
>   scripts/my_python_file.py  
>   DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME} )
> ```

To me, this seems easier than what the tutorial recommends with `setup.cfg` and `setup.py` but maybe I'm missing something. Perhaps it's not Windows-compatible or something like that.

---

Originally posted by [AndyZe](https://answers.ros.org/users/21281/andyze/) with karma: 2331 on 2022-01-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aserbremen](https://answers.ros.org/users/64564/aserbremen/) on 2023-02-24**:
[Here](https://roboticsbackend.com/ros2-package-for-both-python-and-cpp-nodes/) it is said to also use the following command pointing to the directory where the scripts are located (this might be necessary only for certain ROS2 distributions) before using the `install(PROGRAMS...)` command:
`ament_python_install_package(my_package/scripts)`

The making it executable step is really hard to notice. I had the same procedure from another site, but didn't make the python script executable. I could find the python script under `install/my_pacakage/lib/my_pacakage/script.py` but `ros2 run my_pacakage script.py` would throw `No executable found`